# Replace all null values in datacolum by 0 value

Tags: .net, datatable

What's best approach to replace all DBNull values by 0 in datatable without walk through all rows by code. I'm using .NET 2.0 framework.

I try this :

```
 _data_table.Columns(DataColumName).Expression = String.Format("ISNULL({0},0)", DataColumName)
```

But I get 'ArgumentException' Cannot set Expression property due to circular reference in the expression.
I would like to avoid create a temporal duplicated column ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ...without walk through all rows by code.

Just talk through the rows; that's 3 lines of code *tops*:

```
string DataColumnName = ...;
DataColumn col = table.Columns[DataColumnName];
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) if (row.IsNull(col)) row[col] = 0;
```

Less if you make it hard to read. What you are currently trying to do is not going to work. Going forward, you could set a default value.

If this is actually coming from a database, *update it at the database in a single set-based operation*:

```
update [table] set [column] = 0 where [column] is null
```

Comment: or in the query: `SELECT COALESCE(column,0)AS column FROM table`

Comment: Source datatable is provided by external function and I can't modify. If after get I set a default value,this will only set in new added rows.

Comment: @arturn yes, new rows only; until then, *just loop*

Comment: @MarcGravell: But it does not need to change the datasource. How do you know that OP has rights to update or that the table should be updated at all? If he just selects from it anyway, this is the cheapest way to get what he wants. I assume that he fills his `DataTable` via `DataAdapter`, so there are no unnecessary rows involved.

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh, sorry; I misread your comment; I fail at the internet - yes, that would work; but it sounds (OP's comment to me) like that isn't an option

Comment: @MarcGravell: no problem, then i would simply loop the rows as you've shown. That's readable and efficient.